# Excel DO rather than a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro in excel. I have the code just taking a block of data from the spreadsheet by doing this:

> ```
> Range("E1:O25").Select
> Selection.Copy
> ```

I can do this because I know for a fact that on this particular spreadsheet the values I want are sorted into the first 25 lines. For future spreadsheets I will not know that.

```
Range("O1").Select
Do Until Selection.Value <> 0
    'get last cell that has a 0 value
     Selection....
Loop
Range("O1: SELECTIONFROMLOOP").Select
Selection.Copy
```

But I am not sure what it is I should do at 'Selection....'
I was thinking maybe have an incremental variable that counts up but I really don't know VBA best practices. 
Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
Sub duh()
    Dim start As Range: Set start = Range("o1")
    Dim r As Range
    Dim doCopy As Boolean: doCopy = False

    For Each r In Range(start, start.End(xlDown))
        If r.Value <> 0 Then
            If r.Row <> start.Row Then
                Range(start, r.Offset(-1)).Copy
                doCopy = True
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If doCopy Then ActiveSheet.Paste Range("a1")
End Sub
```

First, we define `start` as the cell to start at.  `r` will represent the cell that we are evaluating.  `doCopy` will be set to true if the paste will be done (false if we have nothing to copy).

The `For Each r...` loop will iterate through every cell from `start` through the bottom of the column (this may not be exactly what you want....)

When we find a non-zero value, first check to see if we're still on the first row.  If we are, then we'll just exit the loop.  If we're not on the first row, then `Range(start, r.Offset(-1)).Copy` will copy to the clipboard the range starting at `start` and ending at the cell above `r`; set `doCopy` to True and exit the loop.  Finally, do the paste only if `doCopy` is True.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't like to select a range. Most of the time it is not necessary.
I'd rather also not mess with the clipboard, because it is a big chunk of a "global" variable.

If you just need to move data from "E1:EX" to "O1:OX", I would do the following.

```
i = startRow
do while ThisWorksheet.Cells(i,col1).Text <> ""
    thisWorksheet.Cells(i, targetCol).Value = ThisWorksheet.Cells(i,col1).Text
    i = i + 1
loop
```